# Searching and editing Google sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have an issue with google sheets where i have created a search function that will return a list of matching data, the issue I am having is that the data can not be edited from the returned results as its just a copy.

Is it possible to either edit the data from the returned results or click the cell and that can jump me from the selected cell to the data cell where i can edit the original?

I know this can be done just using the Ctrl+F however the requirement is to have the search function at the top of the sheet locked as it will be years of sales data.

Comment: can be done with jump link - share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 
I am currently using the below to bring up the results using a dropdown in J7 and the input data at K7
=QUERY(A2:H107, "Select * where E "&J7&" '"&K7&"'")

This is returning a list of matching items.
The idea would be that these results are in a locked section at the top of the sheet and clicking the results would either jump to the matching data row or be able to be edited in the results.

We have been using Ctrl+F to find the line but as the sheet has got so big some of the data has been grouped and Ctrl+F will not look in groups when searching.

Comment: @Player0 please see the link below.
[link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tgMmMZ6IThj6UsaFZnh28Jiqci8dAReXOSicWdVbzL0/edit?usp=sharing[link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an example:

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=0&range=B"&MATCH(
 QUERY(A6:P42, "select B where B "&A1&" '"&B1&"'"), B6:B, 0)+ROW(B6)-1, "jump")
```

[image]